# How to store result of cross-table-query to a table variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, table-variable

I actually found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347091/how-to-store-selection-result-in-to-variable-in-oracle-procedure) but I need a syntax for multiple tables.
Example:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR select_results IS
        SELECT T1.ID, T2.DP FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.ROW_ID=T2.DP;
    select_result T1.ID%ROWTYPE, T2.DP%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    -- DO SOMETHING
END;
```

Could someone explain how can I create such custom table variable and is it possible at all?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select_result  select_results%ROWTYPE;
```

Share and enjoy.